# May I say "die Kotlin" (programming language)?

Tags: gender, technical-terminology

Talking of a programming language, which definite article is one supposed to use? As far as I understand, `Programmiersprache` is feminine, does that actually mean that I should say "die Kotlin" or "die Scala" on that rare occasion when I need to use definite article at all.

Such as in

> "It's the Java language, the Java specifications, and the Java runtime."

Comment: _"on that rare occasion when I need to use definite article at all."_ Can you give an example where you think you need to do so?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ pretty much when it's appropriate in English, like in " It's the Java language, the Java specifications, and the Java runtime."

Comment: That makes it easy - the article depends on the second (last) noun, not the language. Check the rules for compound nouns.

Comment: In that case it wouldd be _Es ist die **Spezifikation** der Java Programmiersprache_, same for Kotlin I'd say. But the definite artiicles refer to _die Spezifikation_ / _die Programmiersprache_.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ ok, imagine following context - "you need only one language, and it's the java"

Comment: @shabunc That would be even wrong in Enlish. It should be _you need only one language, and that's java_ (German _Man braucht nur eine Programmiersprache und das ist Java_).

Comment: @shabunc You should add such additional information in your question BTW.

Comment: @Stephie Ich glaube es hat mit Eigennamen zu tun, dass in dem Fall keine Artikel verwendet werden können. Vielleicht kannst Du es ja besser erklären. Schlussendlich habe ich die genannten Beispiele in die Frage kopiert, damit sie beantwortbar ist.

Comment: Der Artikel ist nicht der einzige Ausdruck des Genus eines Wortes. Man kann z.B. sagen "Mein Kollege schreibt fortgeschrittene**s** Java". In solchen Fällen habe ich noch nie etwas anderes als das Neutrum verwendet gesehen.

Comment: No noun inherits it's grammatical gender from a category to which it belongs. Otherwise all humans would be grammatically masculine because *»der Mensch«* is masculine, and at the same time all persons would be grammatically feminine because *»die Person«* is feminine.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In my experience, if the name of a programming language is declared with an article, it is likely neuter; This would only apply to instances, for instance: "das C, das er schreibt".

This applies to language names in general, "Ich verstehe das texanische Englisch kaum". This may well be compared to e.g. "texanisches Englisch". The rules around articles are, uhm, difficult; It depends if the noun is countable, plural, individual, and whether it is used attributively.

#### Programming language names are proper names and as such virtually never used with an article.

> Ich schreibe ein Programm in *Lisp für* Steve. Es wird ein [male] Lisp-Interpreter. Ich schreibe ein [neuter] Lisp in *Lisp*.

The usage is pretty much parallel to English. Except that German marks gender.

After all, a generic, even indefinite *es* is very productive, so it seems to be the default. Phono-semantically, *-in* could become perceived as a female marker, but I find that improbable.

"Die Kotlin-Sprache" strikes me as unidiomatic, and unwieldy on top of that, anyhow.

#### EDIT

habe völlig die Frage verfehlt. Ob du das "darfst" ist eher subjektiv. Soweit "dürfen" von "darben" kommt, hängt die Antwort also davon ab, ob und wie sehr du darbest. Eine körperliche oder emotionale Notlage, die ein Zugeständnis meinerseits erfordern würde sehe ich nicht. Dagegen gibt es aber auch kaum einen Grund es zu verbieten, außer zur Bewahrung eines Zusammengehörigkeit. In diesem Sinne würde die ger.SE Gemeinschaft vermutlich stärkere Argumente wünschen. Du darfst nicht denken "der/die/das Joghurt [-Becher/Schale/Glas]" bedürfte einer Entscheidung.

Comment: _"habe völlig die Frage verfehlt"_ Ich glaube nicht. Es ist in der Tat das Problem mit den _Eigennamen_ [wie erwähnt](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53014/darf-ich-die-kotlin-sagen#comment128870_53014).

Answer (score 12):

First, let me split your question into two ones:

> 1. Talking of a programming language, which definite article [is] one supposed to use?
> 2. [...] *Programmiersprache* is feminine, does that actually mean that I should say "die Kotlin" or "die Scala" on that rare occasion when I need to use definite article at all[?]

In German, languages are typically neuter. This also applies for programming languages. For example, when a definite article is supposed to be used, it is

- das Deutsch
- das Englisch
- das C++
- das Visual Basic
- das Kotlin
- ...

This implies that the answer to your second question, regarding your assumption on the origin of the programming language's gender, is "no, it doesn't". The gender is already determined to be neuter; it does not depend on anything else, such as the gender of *Programmiersprache*.

---

Now, let me turn to your example sentences. Notice that they are of two different kinds.

> It's *the* Java *language*, *the* Java *specifications*, and *the* Java *runtime*.
>   
> ⇆
>   Es ist *die Programmiersprache* Java, *die* Java-*Spezifikationen* und *die* Java-*Laufzeitbibliothek*.

Here, the definite articles *die* belong to the feminine nouns *Programmiersprache*, *Spezifikationen*, and *Laufzeitbibliothek*, respectively, rather than to *Java*. (By the way this is like in English. The articles *the* belong to the nouns *language*, *specification*, and *runtime*, respectively.)

> You need only one language, and it's the java.
>   
> ⇆
>   Man braucht nur eine Sprache, und das ist (das) Java.

Here, the definite article *das* indeed belongs to *Java*. In German, it is typically omitted, which is why I put it into brackets. **When to retain and when to omit it, is not within the scope of this answer.**

---

I want to conclude with examples, where the programming language is in different grammatical cases:

> - Er ist mit *dem Visual Basic* nicht so vertraut.
> - *Das C++* ist ganz schön schwer zu erlernen.
> - Die Vorzüge *des Lisps* sind unverkennbar.
> - Sprecht ihr über *das neue HTML* 5.2?

Comment: Na, herrscht schon wieder Abwerteritis? Der Abwerter möge bitte erklären, wo der Fehler sei.

Comment: Die bestimmten Artikel im letzten Teil würde man vielleicht umgangssprachlich verwenden, aber nicht in formaler oder Schriftsprache, außer wenn eine spezielle Variante der Programmiersprache gemeint ist ("das neue HTML 5.2" ist IMHO OK). Auch das englische Beispiel  "the java" ist falsch, das muss wie ein Eigenname nur "Java" heißen.

Comment: Sag ich ja. Mit "das neue Java" ist ein spezielles Java gemeint, und nicht Java im allgemeinen.

Comment: Java runtime würde ich mit Java-Laufzeitumgebung übersetzen, erst die Java runtime library bringt die Bibliothek ins Spiel - allerdings würde ich Java-Laufzeitumgebung mit JRE zurückübersetzen, also schlicht Java Runtime - da scheint was zu fehlen, aber häufiger die Laufzeitumgebung als die Bibliothek.

Comment: *Die Vorzüge des Lisps sind unverkennbar.* -- ich würde hier vermutlich auf *Die Vorzüge von Lisp sind unverkennbar* ausweichen.

Comment: @Wolf Ich auch, aber ich brauchte ein Beispiel im Genitiv. :-)

Comment: Naja, Ist schon ärgerlich, wenn es einem die eigene Sprache so schwer macht, eine Lanze für sie zu brechen. Wahrscheinlich würde man eher *Die Vorzüge Lisps sind unverkennbar.* schreiben (ohne Artikel und noch mehr Zungenbrecher). Vielleicht wäre Haskell dankbarer gewesen, auch keine so schlechte Sprache ... 

Comment: Ich werte nicht gerne ab, und habe das auch jetzt nicht gemacht, aber die Besipiele am Ende sind außer dem letzten wirklich Quatsch. Niemand würde da Artikel verwenden. Nur bei "das neue" geht es nicht anders.

Answer (score 5):

While the actual question is already answered (language names in German are neuter), your approach for decision-making, visible in

> Programmiersprache is feminine, does that actually mean [...]

shows a misunderstanding that even native German speakers suffer from, namely that gender would follow the gender of [some category](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Categorization) name.

The grammatical gender of the collective name (or category name) gives no indication of the gender of the noun for the things it generalizes. But the category itself may rule the gender. See for example:

Der Baum: *m*

- die Fichte
- die Kiefer
- *most* trees are feminine (this is such a gender rule)
- aber

  - *der* Mammutbaum (compound noun, last word *Baum* dictates gender)
  - *der* Ahorn (one of the exceptions – thanks to bakunin for [the the comment!](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53014/may-i-say-die-kotlin-programming-language#comment172781_58823))
  - *der* Ginkgo (exotic tree whose name [dates back to a transliteration or spelling mistake around 1690](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ginkgo#Etymologie_und_Nomenklatur))

Die Krankheit: *f*

- der Husten
- der Scharlach
- der Schnupfen
- das Asthma
- die Gicht

Das Gefäß: *n*

- der Eimer
- die Tonne
- das Fass

For further information, see

- [Grammatical gender in German - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender_in_German)

  - especially the rules in section [#Noun meanings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_gender_in_German#Noun_meanings)

Comment: Oder der Tiger (m.) ist eine Großkatze (f.) und somit ein Tier (s.). Würden Oberkategorien das Geschlecht der Unterkategorie diktieren, gäbe es nur ein Geschlecht.

Comment: @userunknown Schönes Beispiel. Wobei die Oberkategorien eben teils schon ein Wörtchen mitsprechen (s. Schiffe, Berge, Himmelsrichtungen, ...), allerdings nicht durch "Vererbung" des grammati(kali)schen Geschlechts ihrer Beschriftung. Und das meinte ich eigentlich dargestellt zu haben (ich hätte es lieber auf Deutsch getan (schwer genug), aber das erschien mir bei einer englischen Frage unpassend).

Comment: For a tree which is "genuinely" masculine: der Ahorn

Comment: @bakunin Thanks for the hint, I just updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a definite article (*der*, *die*, *das*) at all, you only use the (proper) name of the programming language:

**Wrong**:

> <s>Die</s> Kotlin ist leicht zu verstehen.
>
> Manche betrachten <s>die</s> Kotlin als den Nachfolger von <s>die</s> Java.

**Correct**:

> Kotlin ist leicht zu verstehen.
>
> Manche betrachten Kotlin als den Nachfolger von Java.

This applies to all programming languages.

Comment: Ich habe eine tl;dr-Antwort hinzugefügt. Sie beinhaltet fast keine neuen Informationen, aber spart dem Leser, der nur eine schnelle Antwort braucht, 10 min seines Lebens. Ich finde, dass unsere Gemeinschaft hier zu oft zu viel schreibt und die Realität ist m.M. nach, dass 90% der Besucher einfach nur eine schnelle Antwort haben wollen. Auf Grund der Ausführlichkeit, fehlenden Struktur und einer tl:dr habe ich auch die bisherigen Antworten abgewertet.